# AWS EC2 + React: “You can now view amplifyapp in the browser.” But failed: This site can’t be reached

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed the steps from AWS “Build a Full-Stack React Application”
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-intro

npx create-react-app amplifyapp
cd amplifyapp
npm start

It says:
Compiled successfully!

You can now view amplifyapp in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://my private IP address:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully

My AWS EC2 uses: Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) – Kernel 5.10, SSD Volume Type, 64-bit.
My AWS EC2 is installed with Apache.

I have tried entering them in my Windows 10 PC browser but none of them succeeded.
Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://my private IP address:3000

Both of them gave me:

This site can’t be reached.
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

How can I fix this React issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `EC2` for this (that's the main reason for `Amplify` to exists), once deployed your app you can check your `Amplify Hosting` account end related `endpoint` from `CLI` (Advanced Users) or from `AWS Website`.

Second, you have to follow exactly all the points in your link, that is intended for users that want to:

> "deploy a `React` application in the `AWS Cloud` by integrating with
> `GitHub` and using `AWS Amplify`"

Third, you probably missed to `Add Authentication` https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/

If your intention is to use `Amplify Hosting` service, here is the full documentation: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/hosting/hosting/